# When someone suddenly loses their everything

Tags: expressions, proverbs

Is there any idiom / expression in English which can imply the situation in which someone due to some bad happenings suddenly and quickly **plummets from the height of success and glory to the depth of wretchidness**?

In my language, there is a proverb which says the same thing usually when someone loses their prior dignity and fame or when they go bankrupt in a short period of time!

Some English equivalents that I have found in translation pages are as below:

> - He raged to riches.
> - He came from somebody to nobody.
> - He came from hero to zero.

I don't know if they work in this sense of natural English! If they do, please let me know; if they don't please tell me the  current expression, idiom or proverb which you use in this situation.

Comment: [wretchedness] Those "equivalents" are all incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He raged to riches. 
He came from somebody to nobody. 
He came from hero to zero.

These "sentences" above look like machine translation and make no sense at all.

Corrections:
- He went from rags to riches. [idiom]

The idiom could be reversed: **He went from riches to rags**. It's creative.

- He went from being a nobody to being a somebody.

Not an idiom but it sounds fine and can be reversed: He Went from being a somebody to being a nobody.

- He went from (being a) hero to (being a) zero. 
  That's fine, but it is not an idiom per se.

To show a fall from on high:

- He fell a long way. or: He has fallen a long way.

Comment: I think "hero to zero" (or vice versa) has become such a cliche that it may be on its way to becoming a standard idiomatic phrase.

Comment: @JamesRandom Well, it rhymes and is clever and ***sounds*** like an idiom but to tell you the truth, I had never heard it.

Answer (score 1):

All the options you talk about (which in their corrected form would be: *go from rags to riches, go from zero to hero, become somebody*) are more common in their positive version, though they could definitely be reversed to indicate a fall in fortunes--riches to rags is fairly common itself.

A few other options are:

- He was **[knocked off his pedestal](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+off+pedestal)**.
- He **[fell from grace](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+from+grace)**.

Like *going from zero to hero* and *becoming somebody*, both of my suggestions are more about status/prestige/public opinion than they are about money.

Comment: The options given by the OP are all off.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, you covered how to fix them, so I only mentioned other options.